# Consecutive string input using std::cin

Tags: c++

I have a `map` where I want to input a last name, and then subsequently enter first names of the family members. I want to hit end of file after entering the first names and then repeat the process.

The following is my code. I am trying to input an end of file, clear it and go to the outer loop. However, when I input end of file it exits both loops. What can I do to prevent this?

Also I know that I can write the program in a different way but I would like to know how I can fix the current code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::string last, children;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> family;
    while(std::cin >> last) {
        while(std::cin >> children) {
            family[last].push_back(children);
        }
        std::cin.clear(~std::istream::eofbit);
    }
    for(const auto &l:family) {
        std::cout << l.first << std::endl;
        for(const auto &c:l.second)
            std::cout << c << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Once you close the input stream, the input stream is closed...

Comment: @KerrekSB of course, but stdin is different and he's not closing it.

Comment: So is there anyway to tweak this to make it run as intended?

Comment: this feels like a slight abuse of the platform, or at least close to the edge. ^Z (I assume that what u are doing)  tells a lot of players in the pipeline that its 'game over'. Just telling the c++ runtime that its not over won't always work. I would change the way I get input. Either make an empty line be the end of children or enter all the children on one line

Comment: @pm100. Ya you might be right. I'm going to abandon this method and use a string stream instead.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `std::ios::clear()` in a wrong way. Setting it to *not eofbit* results in other fail bits being set. Remove the parameter passed to `clear()` or use `std::ios::goodbit`, which is the same, to recover the cin from EOF.

Reference: [ios::clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)

Comment: I used just clear() by itself also but that also exits the loop.

Comment: Works for me in MinGW. What's your input though?